# CSS mask on element w/ no image?

Tags: javascript, css, mask, clip

**The Problem:** 

I have a set of "tabs" for navigation that I want to add a "mask" class to the tab that is active..My goal is to reveal the BODY's background color and/or background image of the page, but only with this "active" tab. Since the body's background page is dynamic and always changing, I can't simply add a background color to the "active tab" and call it a day. I have to use a different technique (javascript is last resort, I want to do this w/ CSS only).

**Requirments:**

- I can't use an image for the mask because the "tab"
  widths are css displayed w/ flexbox and stretch across the page.
- I have to use a solution that masks ELEMENTS only... In this case:
  `<div class="mask"></div>`
- I can't rearrange the HTML structure below.. I have to work w/
  this layout.

---

Is this possible w/ the css mask or is there a better way to achieve this with a different css technique?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/7mj8voL8/

---

**CODE:**

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

/* Body */
body { background-color: rgb(0, 121, 191); }

/* Header */
h1 { color: white;  }
header { background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .15); padding: 20px 20px 0; }
header nav { display: flex; }
header nav div { flex: 1; color: white; background: rgba(0,0,0, .1); margin: 10px 10px 0; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; }

/* Mask (without image?) */
header nav div.mask { background: rgba(0,0,0, .1); } /* Can mask reveal background color? */

/* Main */
main { padding: 20px 20px 0; }
h2 { color: rgba(0,0,0, .54); }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  
  <nav>
    <div class="mask">Link (mask)</div>
    <div class="">Link</div>
    <div class="">Link</div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <h2>CSS Masking</h2>
  <p>Possible to css mask without an image? Hmmmmmm.......</p>
  
  <p>I want to reveal the color of the BODY's background on the DIV that has the class "mask"</p>
</main>
```

Comment: If your body's background is a solid colour, you simply have to assign the same colour to the `.mask` class. However, it's difficult if you have a background image—since you are also setting a background for the `<header>` element, a CSS mask would not work (at least at the level of the `<div class="mask">`, because it will only reveal the parent background (the dimmed header background) instead of the root background (body background). You might have to reconsider your design and/or markup options.

Comment: This is actually being created for a Trello extension.. It would be awesome if I could re-write some of there HTML, but not an option. I see what you mean with it only revealing the parents dimmed background color.. hmm....

Comment: Your only chance is javascript, you have to listen to every change that affect the position of the div and the background (css, resize, scroll), and recalculate the offset for the background clip. It's quite easy to do so, but the performance might not be as expected.

Comment: yeah..that might be a little performance intense. One technique I tried... in theory seemed like would work (but failed): applying a white tranpsarent "rgba(255,255,255, .15)" (the opposite black dim color) for the tab background in order bring it's "natural" color back.. though it's close, my knowledge of how transparency and colors operate has fallen short haha..

Comment: You know what I could do though? Use margin to push the "tab" layer onto the BODY. It's a bit hacky and I hate that idea, really...but If I could use the mask effect on the element, this might could work.

Answer (score 0):

If there is always an active element , and only one active element, you can set a shadow on it that gets the desired effect (instead of the background on the header)

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

/* Body */
body { background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, lightblue 0px, lightgreen 100px); }

/* Header */
h1 { color: white;  }
header {  padding: 20px 20px 0; }
header nav { display: flex; }
header nav div { flex: 1; color: white; background: rgba(0,0,0, .1); margin: 10px 10px 0; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; }

/* create a shdow on the underlying element, reset the default bkg */
header nav div.mask { 
  box-shadow: 0px -1000px 0px 1000px rgba(0,0,0, .1); 
  background-color: transparent;
} 

/* Main */
main { padding: 20px 20px 0; }
h2 { color: rgba(0,0,0, .54); }
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Logo</h1>
  
  <nav>
    <div class="mask">Link (mask)</div>
    <div class="">Link</div>
    <div class="">Link</div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <h2>CSS Masking</h2>
  <p>Possible to css mask without an image? Hmmmmmm.......</p>
  
  <p>I want to reveal the color of the BODY's background on the DIV that has the class "mask"</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Your code produced a repeating gradient over the entire page..I think I understand your approach, but I'm not sure your code result matches what your saying: http://i.imgur.com/mTl20Ap.png

Comment: I changed the background in the body, to make clearer what the body was. just change it back to the original, and the result should be ok